# Total Number of different playable chords

Tags: permutations, combinations, permutation-cycles

Suppose that I have a very special Ukulele that contains ***N*** frets.
I can use atmost ***4 fingers*** to play a chord.
I am required to determine the ***total number of different chords*** that I can play.

Note: Two chords are different if one of the frets that are pressed in one of the chords is not pressed in another chord.

Comment: On a real instrument, notes overlap, e.g. fret $5+n$ on string $2$ or $3$ is the same note as fret $n$ on the next string. Do you consider chords the same if the (multi-)set of their notes coincide? E.g. is chord $(x, 7,6,x)$ the same as $(x, x, 2,1)$, where $x$ means no note on the given string?

Comment: Hi @Berd it's just hypothetical scenerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is ambiguous as to exactly what constitutes a chord in this case but I see two reasonable interpretations.

The first interpretation is that all the strings are tuned the same and so having a fret pressed on one string is considered the same as if it were pressed on the other string.  The question reworded in more math-heavy terms becomes "*How many subsets of size $4$ or less exist for an $N$ element set?*"

Well... there are $\binom{N}{k}$ subsets of size $k$ of an $N$ element set, so our answer here is simply $\binom{N}{0}+\binom{N}{1}+\binom{N}{2}+\binom{N}{3}+\binom{N}{4}$, the number of ways of pressing zero frets or pressing one fret or pressing two frets, etc...

---

The other interpretation that seems natural enough is that each string is tuned differently and so the chord that is made by pressing (*or not pressing*) frets is also dependent on which string it was that the fret was pressed on.  Ukelele typically have four strings, one for each available finger.  Here, we ask "Which fret is pressed for the first string?  Which fret is pressed for the second string? etc..." keeping in mind that not pressing a fret on that string is also an option.  The question reworded in more math heavy terms becomes "how many functions are there from a 4 element set to an $N+1$ element set?"

As each finger has $N+1$ options (*each fret being an option and the additional option of not having pressed a fret*), we apply the rule of product to arrive at a total of $(N+1)\times (N+1)\times (N+1)\times (N+1) = (N+1)^4$

Comment: As a matter of fact if N = 5  our answer should be 30

Comment: @AnshulGupta that sounds incorrect, but perhaps it was using my first interpretation with the additional condition that at least one fret must be pressed.  That would give an answer of $\binom{N}{1}+\binom{N}{2}+\binom{N}{3}+\binom{N}{4}$ which in the case of $N=5$ would give $5+10+10+5=30$.  I disagree with this however on the principle that having pressed no frets is still a valid chord in practice.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help  @JMoravitz